# bootstrap 5 columns in one row

Tags: html, css

[Five equal columns in twitter bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10387740/five-equal-columns-in-twitter-bootstrap)

[Bootstrap - 5 column layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31944691/bootstrap-5-column-layout)

[5 columns per row in Bootstrap-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50734727/5-columns-per-row-in-bootstrap-4)

I have already looked at these links but still not found an issue
I have tried to get 5 columns in a row with below

css

```
.col-xs-offset-13{
    margin-left:4.166666667%;
}
```

html

```
<div class="col-xs-2">1</div>
<div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-13">2</div>
<div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-13">3</div>
<div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-13">4</div>
<div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-13">5</div>
```

but the result I get is 6 columns in a row. any ideas would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a `col-xx` class without a column size :

```css
div div div {
  border: solid;
  margin: 2px;/* this can be added without breaking the row */
}
div div div:before {
content:attr(class);/* show class used */
color:crimson
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<p>Class used , play snippet in full page to test behavior on resizing :</p>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm"></div>
    <div class="col-sm"></div>
    <div class="col-sm"></div>
    <div class="col-sm"></div>
    <div class="col-sm"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md"></div>
    <div class="col-md"></div>
    <div class="col-md"></div>
    <div class="col-md"></div>
    <div class="col-md"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Include in your CSS style:

```
.custom-col{
    width: 20%;
    word-break:break-all;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="custom-col">CONTENT</div>
      <div class="custom-col">CONTENT</div>
      <div class="custom-col">CONTENT</div>
      <div class="custom-col">CONTENT</div>
      <div class="custom-col">CONTENT</div>
</div>
```

**It worked for me!**

Comment: The edit queue is full, please remove the "It worked for me!" and substitute it for some code explanation and maybe documentation.